# How to use javascript promises that waits for jquery ajax to finish before moving onto next promise?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, es6-promise

How to use javascript promises that waits for jquery ajax to finish before moving onto next promise?

```
 bookmakers = [
                "bet365","skybet","ladbrokes","williamhill","betfred","paddypower","sportingbet","betvictor","unibet","totesport","coral","boylesports","betstars","blacktype","betfair","betway","betbright","32red","10bet","marathonbet","118bet","888sport","stanjames","winner"
            ];

 function doSomethingAsync(value, dabookie) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        ///////////////////
        console.log("get ajax for "+dabookie);
        tasking = "";
        dataString = "";

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "testscraperules.php?task="+dabookie,
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        timeout: 6000,
        statusCode: {
            404: function() {
                //alert("Error 404");
                $("."+dabookie+" td").addClass("yellowback");
                $("."+dabookie+" .loading").replaceWith("<img src='cross.png' width='24' height='24' />");
            },
            503: function(){ // Service Unavailable (server access throttling)
                $("."+dabookie+" td").addClass("magentaback");
                $("."+dabookie+" .loading").replaceWith("<img src='cross.png' width='24' height='24' />");
                //alert("Error 504 Gateway Timeout when accessing \n testscraperules.php?task="+dabookie);
            },
            504: function(){ // Gateway Timeout
                $("."+dabookie+" td").addClass("purpleback");
                $("."+dabookie+" .loading").replaceWith("<img src='cross.png' width='24' height='24' />");
                //alert("Error 504 Gateway Timeout when accessing \n testscraperules.php?task="+dabookie);
            }
        }, success: function(html){

            // alert("bookmaker in success is \n"+dabookie);

            var jsonstring = $(html).filter("textarea").val(); //alert(jsonstring);
            if(jsonstring == ""){
                $("."+dabookie+" td").addClass("amberback");
                $("."+dabookie+" .loading").replaceWith("<img src='cross.png' width='24' height='24' />");
            }
            jsonstring = "{ \""+dabookie+"\": [ "+jsonstring+" ] }"; //for multiple results 6 horses x 25 bookmakers

            console.log(jsonstring); 

        }, error: function(XMLHttpRequest, status, message){
        }
        });

        //////
      console.log("Resolvingx " + dabookie);
      resolve(value);
    }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
  });
}

    function test() {
      let i;
      let promises = [];
      console.log(bookmakers.length);
      for (i = 0; i < bookmakers.length; ++i) {
        promises.push(doSomethingAsync(i, bookmakers[i]));
      }

      Promise.all(promises)
          .then((results) => {
            console.log("All done", results);
          })
          .catch((e) => {
              // Handle errors here
          });
    }

    // test();

    $(".goscrape").click(function (){
        test();
    });
```

[image: promises not working]

As you can see from the Console, the ajax is preventing the promises from running in order. It should wait until one promise is finished before moving onto the next one.

What is going on

Comment: asnyc/await?  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: You need to resolve the promise in the ajax success function, not after a random timeout....

Comment: I'm new to javascript promises. I see the timeout now. How do I resolve a javascript promise?

Comment: With the "resolve" function that you pass as an argument to your Promise. This line `resolve(value);`

Comment: just call your resolve

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now my scraper works! :)

Comment: As I said in the other thread; Promise.all won't ensure execution order, just that each of your promises is resolved, this is probably preferable for your use case as you probably don't want one slow ajax call to hold everything else up. Chaining a 'then' onto the Promise.all call should eventually resolve to give you an ordered array of resolved promises (same order as you added them to the promises array). You can then use whatever logic you like to loop over the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do something with recursion like this if you want to make sure that the promises run in order:

```
function test() {
  runPromise(0);
}

function finish(err) {
  if (err) console.log(err);
  console.log('finished!');
}

function runPromise(index) {
  // jump out of loop if there are no more bookmakers
  if (index >= bookmakers.length) return finish();

  doSomethingAsync(index, bookmakers[index]).then((value) => {
    // do something with the value
    // ...
    // iterate to the next promise
    runPromise(index + 1);
  }).catch((err) => {
    // break out of loop when an error occurs
    finish(err);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is no guarantee for Promise.all to resolve all promises in order.
Promises begin their tasks when they are created, and Promise.all simply awaits them to resolve.
If you are looking for a way for them to resolve in order, you can use

```
promises.reduce((promise,function) => p.then(function),Promise.resolve());
```